# How to count recursively and display the number of all sub-directories for a working directory?

Tags: unix

Hey guys. Just like in the title - I'm having some problems doing it. Basically, I want to create an alias in my enviromental file that would count recursively and display the number of all sub-directories of a working directory. Could someone provide me with adequate group of shell commands? I'm using Korn shell. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias dircount="find . -type d 2> /dev/null | wc -l"
```

should work. But don't forget, that it skips directories for which you doesn't have access rights.

HTH

Comment: Does this set of commands also include the ones with invisible file names?

Comment: Yes, it finds the directories [which names are] starting with dot too.